# Enter key press in C#

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-events

I tried this code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 13) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Enter pressed ");
    }
}
```

and this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Enter pressed ");
    }
}
```

and this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Enter pressed ");
    }
}
```

but they're not working...

When I write something and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it doesn't work. It only highlights my text.

Comment: Is your textbox MultiLine == true?

Comment: Getting the Enter key to "highlight text" is a remarkable trick.  Describe what properties of the TextBox are displayed in bold in the Properties window and what other events you've implemented.

Comment: i tried multiline false and true its not change anything.... :( :(

Comment: text box properties  bold ones:  lines : String[] Array   --- location and size , tab index:14 --name -- anchor-- autocomplete custom : collection(inside collection nothing ) autocompletemode suggest autocomplete source : recentlyusedlist

Comment: The AutoComplete settings cause this behavior.  You can still detect the key if you use KeyDown instead.

Comment: Sounds like sticky keys :D

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try this code,might work (Assuming windows form):

```
private void CheckEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        // Enter key pressed
    }
}
```

Register the event like this :

```
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new 
System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckEnter);
```

Comment: it works now thanks... :D i changed auto complete mode to none :D

Comment: `if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)` makes my pedantic side smile

Comment: even `if (e.KeyChar == (Int32)Keys.Enter)` works, I usually cast enum as int

Comment: @sgissinger why cast something that is only ever going to be 2 bytes to 4 bytes?  e.KeyChar is a char (2 bytes) not a Int32 (4 bytes).

Comment: @nashwan you're right it's useless in this case. I was talking about enums in general. For example, Keys.Shift equals 65536 which can't be cast as a 2 bytes char (or short).

Answer (score 42):

You must try this in keydown event

here is the code for that :

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed");
        }
    }
```

Update :

Also you can do this with keypress event.

Try This :

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Key pressed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DoğaÖzkaracaabatlıoğlu make the form key preview to true

Comment: Keys.Enter instead Key.Enter

Comment: KeyEventArgs does not have a property "Key", so the first example doesn't compile - it does have "KeyCode"

Comment: why "must"? key down triggers before user release the key and keyup might trigger in a different control (based on what it supposed to do)

Comment: In case you want to prevent another event which is also registered to react on the enter key, you need to add ` e.Handled=true;` - this is important if you want to implement something like performing an "OK action" when pressing Enter.

Answer (score 8):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Pressed");
    }
}
```

This allows you to choose the specific Key you want, without finding the char value of the key.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void textBoxKontant_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed");
            }
        }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Key_press event you may use Key_down event. You can find this as below[image: Event]

after double clicking here it will automatically this code

```
private void textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

     }
```

Problem solved now use as you want.

```
private void textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Enter pressed ");
        }
     }
```

Comment: This has already been said by many others, e.g.[the second-highest rated answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12318406/1364007).

Comment: Since we all are here to learn here I am also contributing. After all, I have to learn to answer. After answering this I came to know a lot of things. As well for the next time, i will surely keep in mind your comment.

Answer (score 3):

KeyChar is looking for an integer value, so it needs to be converted as follows:

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToInt16(Keys.Enter))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Testing KeyPress");
        }
    }
```

Comment: or just use `13` instead of `Convert.ToInt16(Keys.Enter))` which does not need any calculations. As an alternative you can use a jQuery plugin to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
private void TextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed");
     }
 }
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed");
        }
    }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do this with keypress event.

```
 private void textBox1_EnterKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

 {

  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
     // some code what you wanna do
   }


}
```

Comment: keypress `e` argument is of type `KeyPressEventArgs`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the best solution:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that

**Keys.Return** is different to **Keys.Enter**

```
//Makes it easier to Type user and password and press Enter, 
//Rather than using the mouse to Click the Button all the time
    private void Txt_Password_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            Btn_Login_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Ctrl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

Select all required textboxes; type in new Events name Ctrl_KeyUp.

See YouTube by BTNT TV:
https://www.bing.com/videos/searchq=c%23+how+to+move+to+next+textbox+after+enterkey&view=detail&mid=999E8CAFC15140E867C0999E8CAFC15140E867C0&FORM=VIRE

Answer (score -1):

You could use this code:

```
abc_KeyDown(abc, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        switch (e.Key.ToString())
        {
                case "Return":
                        MessageBox.Show(" Enter pressed ");
                        break;
         }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work on Threads with CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture other than English.

Comment: i get this error : Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Doğa\Doga Rhodonit\Doga Rhodonit\Doga Rhodonit\Form1.cs 380 23 Doga Rhodonit