# Can anyone help about Calculator code in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

please help me about this code.
this code can run when the user press Enterkey
but i dont khow how to solve this.
problem in the line problem.
** I want Know KeyCode for EnterKey

```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        if (panel1.Enabled)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9')
            {
                Numbers(b, null);
                foreach (Button c in panel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.Text == b.Text)
                    {
                        c.Focus();

                    }
                }
            }
            else
             if (e.KeyChar == 13)
                    btnequal.Focus();

                if (e.KeyChar == '+' || e.KeyChar == '-' || e.KeyChar == '/' || e.KeyChar == '*')
                {
                    Operations(b, null);
                    foreach (Button c in panel1.Controls)
                    {
                        if (c.Text == b.Text)
                        {
                            c.Focus();

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    if (e.KeyChar == '.')
                    {
                        btndot_Click(null, null);
                        btndot.Focus();
                    }
                    else
                        if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
                        {
                            btnbackspace_Click(b, null);
                            btnbackspace.Focus();
                        }
                        else
               line problem           ===>  if (e.KeyChar =='\n')
                                MessageBox.Show("you press enter");
        }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter key press in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318164/enter-key-press-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of these to see when the Enter/Return key is pressed:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
if (e.KeyChar == 13)
if (e.KeyChar == 0x0D)
```

Comment: Just a note for Pooya; unless you have a reason to use the last 2 Tim mentioned, stick to one of the first two. They're much more readable and I'd argue that most people wouldn't know what `13` or `0x0D` are off the top of their heads, where as `\r` and `(char)Keys.Return are much more explicit.