# How to perform functions on keyboard press c#

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# and I want to know how can I press a key on my keyboard say the <kbd>Q</kbd> key and have it preform a list of functions? 
I want to form a list of function under neath it. Anybody have any idea how to do this? thanks

```
//Something like this
if keyboard_down(Q)
{
     //Do events here
}
```

I know this isn't the right function but that is basically what i want it to do. Winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention which technology you work with.
I will assume that you are using Winforms.

In order to react to Key Press event you need to use `Control.OnKeyPress` - [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318164/enter-key-press-in-c-sharp)  which shows how to handle 'enter' key press

Comment: I need it to preform and loop the actions if the key is down not just pressed

Comment: OK, look for `Control.OnKeyDown` and `Control.OnKeyUp`events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx

and 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeyup(v=vs.110).aspx

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the way you want it.

Do you want them to fire while the form got focus or even without any focus to the form?

**With focus:**
Click your form in the form-designer and then go to the properties-tab. Click that little lightning bolt on top of it. There are a lot of events in that list. Double click "Keypress" and it will create an event automaticly and open the right code-snipped for you.

*Depending on the focus you want, you can also mark controlls inside the form designer and then create the keypress event.*

**Without focus:**
This would be a bit more difficultly. Here you would need to use a global keyboard hook to permanently grab pressed keys. Google for "c# keyboard hook". There are some examples out there.