# How do I make it so pressing Enter in a textbox does the same as clicking the button next to it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a C# based chat client in Windows Forms. I want to make it so a user won't always have to click the button when they want to send a message. Instead, hitting the `Enter` or `Return` key should be sufficient.

Here is a screnshot of my Form:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter key press in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318164/enter-key-press-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you add some code you have written so far.

Comment: Sure thing: http://prntscr.com/iqhhsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `Keydownevent` for the textbox and ask for the enter key:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I only get the system sound as if I had pressed an invalid button.

Comment: That's a KeyDown event _handler_. The event already exists. @Jan-HendrikLorenzen Why isn't it working? Do you get errors? Did you register for the event?

Comment: No error messages, just Windows giving me a chime sound as if I was pressing an invalid key or trying to click a disabled button.

Comment: If you put a break point into the event handler, does it get hit when debugging?

Comment: @Jan-HendrikLorenzen Did you add the event handler to the associated event? For example like this: https://prnt.sc/iqii3a
Btw. I'd recommend to not only comment in english like you already do, but also name the variables, objects and the whole code with english terms. It's better if somebody that is not familiar with german has still no problem to edit it.

Comment: Ooooh! No, I haven't! It works now, but I still get the sound effect.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your textbox keydown event to check whether you have pressed enter or not then call the submit button click event from there,

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        buttonsSubmit_Click(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Handle KeyPress event for your textbox and code it like below in .cs page

```
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your code here for enter key", "Enter Pressed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me, but at least it doesn't crash unlike the wonky workaround I had attempted before.

Comment: _"The KeyPress event is not raised by non-character keys other than space and backspace;"_ -> [Control.KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: add your code that throws you an error.. so I can help you there.
The code i have posted is in working mode for enter key. @Fildor

Comment: Hm, odd. Then that is working in contradiction to docs, imho.

Comment: The code doesn't exist anymore. I overwrote it with yours.

Comment: In my code problem are you facing? I can help you at there.

Comment: No problem, it simply seems to not do anything. I even out a break in and it still didn't react in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `KeyPress` event of the TextBox to know which key is pressed. When the Return key is pressed, programmatically click the `Senden` button.

Event Handler:

```
private void CheckEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
   {
     // Enter key pressed
   }
}
```

And register the event like this (or use the visual editor):

```
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckEnter);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12318224/1392490)