# Why is my C# WinForms window not closing in response to Enter key?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keydown, showdialog

I have a basic WinForms project where the user clicks a button. This opens another form as follows:

```
form2 myForm2 = new form2();
myForm2.ShowDialog();
```

Inside this new form, there are four buttons which represent values. The user presses the SPACE key to jump between buttons and the ENTER key to select one. When the user presses ENTER on a button I want the form to close. For this is I use 'this.Close()'. This works for absolutely fine with every key other than ENTER. I am using visual studio so I have inserted a break point and stepped over the code. The ENTER key is detected successully and I can step over the code 'this.Close()' but the window never closes. My code is a followed:

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
         // Change colour of the button you are on. This works fine.
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.Close(); 
        // This will close the form with all keys other than the Enter key. Yet the enter key is 
        // successfully detected and the program enters this else if statement.
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: With the explanation you gave, you should call the click event!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318164/enter-key-press-in-c-sharp

Comment: You have code written for click event also ?

Comment: pushing on `enter` on a button is actually like clicking on it, so the `onclick` event will probably eat your event. I guess you can assign a click event and try if you can check there if someone pushed on the enter key

Comment: The Enter key is special, along with Escape, Tab and the cursor keys.  Used for navigation, it activates the form's AcceptButton.  Which is one way to solve it, or use the PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: @HansPassant: The OP has stated that the enter key is detected successfully... so either the special nature of enter is a red herring here, or their diagnostics are somewhat broken.

Comment: `PreviewKeyDown` should be used to catch the enter key + `BeginInvoke` should be used to call `this.Close()`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, why would you need to invoke the close call?

Comment: @Idle_Mind As I explained in the answer: `this.BeginInvoke()` is necessary here as you have shown the form using `ShowDialog`. If you open the form by using Show, you don't need `BeginInvoke`. I didn't check the source code to see what's the problem here, there should be something wrong (or maybe by design) with modal message loop.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I see that YOU said it is required.  Where in the documentation does it say that you must use invoke because of ShowDialog()?  Never heard of such a thing...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I didn't see anything related to this in documentation, but you can give it a try :)

Comment: OP is already using `PreviewKeyDown`, look at event handler signature: `(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd override `ProcessCmdKey()` and make the space key act like the tab key to select the next control.  Then just handle each the click event of each button like normal.  The click handler for the buttons will fire when the user presses enter:

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        Button btn = this.ActiveControl as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Space)
            {
                // possibly do something else with "btn"?...
                this.SelectNextControl(btn, true, true, true, true);
                return true; // suppress default handling of space
            }
        }            
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // possibly set some value?
        Console.WriteLine("button1");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // possibly set some value?
        Console.WriteLine("button2");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // possibly set some value?
        Console.WriteLine("button3");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // possibly set some value?
        Console.WriteLine("button4");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

}
```

An alternative approach would be to also trap the enter key in `ProcessCmdKey()` like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        Button btn = this.ActiveControl as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Space)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Space -> Tab");
                // possibly do something else with "btn"?...
                this.SelectNextControl(btn, true, true, true, true);
                return true; // suppress default handling of space
            }
            else if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in ProcessCmdKey() for " + btn.Name);
                // possibly do something else with "btn"?...
                this.Close();
                // < or >
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                return true;
            }
        }            
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into signature of the handler `(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)` apparently OP is already handling `PreviewKeyDown` event.

I reproduced and solved the problem.

The behavior is different when you open a Form using `Show` or `ShowDialog`. Everything works as expected with `Show`, but when using `ShowDialog`, to close the form in `PreviewKeyDown`, you need to use one of the following options:

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsInputKey = true; 
    this.Close();

    // OR 
    // if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    //     this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Close())); 

    // OR first hide, then close, without calling BeginInvoke
    // this.Hide();
    // this.Close();
}
```

There should be something about model message loop. I didn't traced in details, but you may find the following links useful:

- [LocalModalMessageLoop in Application](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,3560)
- [CheckCloseDialog in Form](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,9e5ff82765459e00)
- [WMClose in Form](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,835f7070c7e52263)

Just as a side note: If the <kbd>Enter</kbd> should be handled at form level, then setting `AcceptButton` of the form or overriding `ProcessKeyDown` or `ProcessDialogKey` of the form is the way to go.

Comment: I popped this into your `button1_PreviewKeyDown()` method: `Console.WriteLine("this.InvokeRequired = " + this.InvokeRequired);` and it output FALSE.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Just give it a try without `BeginInvoke` to see what's the difference. Also pay attention to `BEGINinvoke`, it's not `Invoke`, and it just queues the operation until after finishing the processing of current message.

Comment: I can see that it doesn't work without BeginInvoke.  The same issue is not present when you use `ProcessCmdKey()` at the Form level as in my example.  I was just trying to find some documentation as to WHY you need that extra BeginInvoke.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I guess you will not find any documentation for that, but maybe some clue by tracing  [`LocalModalMessageLoop` in `Application`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,3560) or [`CheckCloseDialog` in `Form`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,9e5ff82765459e00)
 [`WMClose` in `Form`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,835f7070c7e52263), etc.

Comment: @Idle_Mind  another option: First hide, then close, without calling `BeginInvoke`, like this:
`this.Hide(); this.Close();`

Comment: Yet another one, the better one:  `e.IsInputKey = true; this.Close();`

Comment: @ba126 I've tested all the proposed suggestions and they work properly for me, so let me know if you find any problem with them.